# Meanings of 可愛くない

Tags: meaning, words

The main meaning of 可愛くない is of course "not cute", but I think I've heard/seen the word in other contexts, too. Is it possible for 可愛くない to be a kind of insult, like "loser" maybe? Especially when it's used for boys?

Comment: Do you have any particular example context(s) you'd like to add to your question, so people can comment on how they'd interpret it in those specific examples?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment. I just read a scene in a manga where a girl says about a boy (her friend) that he's 可愛くない, but there's no further context. I just think it doesn't mean "he's not cute" (or maybe I just think that because I would never say that in English?)

Comment: 「素直じゃない」・「可愛いげがない(可愛いげのない～)」て意味でも使いますよね

Answer (score 10):

可愛い has [a wide variety of meanings](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%8F%AF%E6%84%9B%E3%81%84), but in your case it probably means "adorable", "innocent", "docile" or "childlike". For example, if a 9-year-old boy refuses to help his mom after saying a sarcastic and argumentative remark about money, that can be 可愛くない.

Comment: At least in anime it's imho often used as a joke in that the target person of such remark wouldn't have wanted to be called 可愛い in the first place

Comment: @NoxArt Something like 可愛くねえガキだな is not a joke at all.

Comment: True, something like that isn't ... it was probably a wrong term, well ... I imagined it in a more lighthearted way (perhaps like teasing) so it probably depends on intonation...

Answer (score 6):

I sometimes see it used in the sense of "mean" or "ungrateful":

> お前は可愛くない性格だな。
>
> You're not very nice.
>
> せっかくドーナツ買ってきてあげたのに可愛くない！
>
> I bought you donuts and you're not even thankful!